# avoiding Maximum call stack size exceeded when calling function in itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a function for checking a proxy list , this list i getting updated overtime so i need this function to keep checking over and over here is what is have ... im using nodejs so this is not in the browser

```
var STACK = [] ;
async function check_proxy(){

    if(STACK.length < 1 )
    {
    setTimeout(()=>check_proxy() , 2000 );
    return ;
    }




    var ipport =  STACK.pop();

    console.log(`------- checking ${ipport}---------`);
    await open_browser(ipport);
    check_proxy();
}

async function open_browser(){
// do proxy checking 
}

check_proxy();
```

but i  keep getting

```
(node:3052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at check_proxy (C:\wamp64\www\robot\proxy-check.js:1:1)
    at check_proxy (C:\wamp64\www\robot\proxy-check.js:42:16)
    at check_proxy (C:\wamp64\www\robot\proxy-check.js:42:16)
    at check_proxy (C:\wamp64\www\robot\proxy-check.js:42:16)
    at check_proxy (C:\wamp64\www\robot\proxy-check.js:42:16)
```

i understand why im getting this error , but how can i avoide it ? i dont want to use setInterval because i want the function check each proxy right after the last one is done and i dont know how long each of them will take

mostly im getting this error in here

```
    if(STACK.length < 1 )
        return setTimeout(()=>check_proxy() , 2000 );
```

when the stack is empty .... which happens from time to time and this array will get populated by another function over time

i can raise setTimeout here so it wouldn't call itself so fast , but im not sure how javascript works and i might get this error anyway  ... i mean im not sure is the number of calling in a specific period of time that cuzes this ... or the time is not a factor and i will get this with current structure even if i increase the time between calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an infinite loop instead of a recursive call:

```
const STACK = [];

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

async function check_proxy() {
    while (true) {
        if (STACK.length === 0) {
            await sleep(2000);
            continue;
        }

        const ipport = STACK.pop();

        console.log(`------- checking ${ipport}---------`);
        await open_browser(ipport);
    }
}
```

This also lends itself to waiting for a signal that `STACK` isn’t empty anymore instead of waiting a fixed 2 seconds to check again.